# How to send the data of a list group item to a controller function using an http get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an application in c# using the asp.net mvc web application platform. In my index.cshtml I have a list group div called 'results'. When a user clicks one of the items in the div, I would like to send the data in the item to a function in an api controller. I've attempted to do this, but when I click on an item, I get no response at all.

```
<script>

    $('.list-group-item').on('click', function () {
        var artist = $(this).val();


        $.get("/api/Search/related?artistId=" + artist.ArtistId, function (data) {
            $("results").html("");

            if (data.Data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
                    $("#results").append('<button type= "button" class="list-group-item">' + data.Data[i] + '</button>');
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#results").html("<p style=\"text-align:center\">No results were found!! :(</p>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The contents of the 'results' div are populated correctly with another javascript function. Here is the html for results:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <div class="list-group" id="results">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Post to send complex data.

Comment: the function in my search controller makes the get call @Shyju